# implementing code with "and" and "jg" or "jle" | how

Tags: assembly, x86

I tried to solve a question shown below;

*By just using and, and jg or jle,  how can one implement following code?*

```
    if %eax > 4 
        jmp do
    else 
        jmp l1
```

*of course without changing value of eax*

This question is taken from a textbook, but it has no answer. Can you show me how to solve it?

EDIT:
I have tried ;

```
     subl $4, %eax
     andl %eax, %eax
     jg  do
     jmp l1
      .
      .
      .
     do :
     addl $4, %eax
      .
      .
      .
     l1:
     addl $4, %eax
```

Comment: Hi - I *thought* I knew the answer ... but I was wrong.  Good question!  Frankly, your solution isn't bad...

Comment: well.. if we're talking about unsigned number interpretations here, the check for `> 4` can be done by `and`ing with `0xFFFFFFFC` (assuming 32 bit).

Comment: `0xFFFFFFFC` is `~(4-1)`

Comment: @noah1989: it modifies eax and thus is unacceptable.

Comment: @RomanR.: so well.. if `and` is unaccaptable we're left with only `jg` and `jle`. good luck.

Comment: as @Alex pointed out, `and` **is** acceptable, if eax doesn't appear on the left side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below sequence of `and` and `jle` solves the problem (NASM syntax is used):

```
; start execution here if eax is treated as an unsigned integer
unsigned_eax:
    and     dword [eighty - 3], eax
    and     dword [eighty], 80H
    jle     signed_eax ; jumps if eax <= 7FFFFFFFh, continues otherwise
    and     dword [eighty], 0
    jle     do ; jumps if eax > 7FFFFFFFh = always

; start execution here if eax is treated as a signed integer
signed_eax:
    and     dword [FFFFFFFC], eax
    jle     l1 ; jumps if eax < 4, continues if eax >= 4
    and     dword [FFFFFFFB], eax
    jle     l1 ; jumps if eax = 4, continues if eax > 4
    and     dword [zero], 0 ; this and the next instruction simulate "jmp do"
    jle     do
do:
    ; some code
l1:
    ; some code

FFFFFFFC    dd 0FFFFFFFCH
FFFFFFFB    dd 0FFFFFFFBH
zero        dd 0
eighty      dd 80H
```

The caveat here is that this is a use-once piece of code because it irreversibly modifies 2 (or 3) variables.

Answer (score 1):

Is something wrong with `cmp`?

```
cmp eax, 4
jg do
jmp l1
```

If jmp is not allowed, you can do it like this:

```
cmp eax, 4
jg do
jle l1
```

If you were allowed to modify eax (or use `mov` or `push`/`pop`), the answer would be:

```
and eax, eax // This line and the one below is to be removed if the value is unsigned
jle l1
and eax, 0xFFFFFFFC // not 3
jle l1
jg do
```

Comment: cmp is wrong because the assignment asks for "and", "jle" or "jg" (if this is a good assignment is another point, but it is clear regarding the instruction that should be used).

Comment: The assignment is actually defined bad: it shows an attempt to solve using `sub`, which is clearly not allowed, but it also does not mention if flavours of `mov`s are allowed. Any plain `and` would modify register so the assignment has no solution unless clarified.

Comment: another thing that's not defined is how the value of `eax` is to be interpreted. signed? unsigned? floating-point? also, are we allowed to trash the value of other registers? because with only `and` all we can do is clear bits, there is no way to restore anything we changed.

Comment: yeah, I think the "don't modify eax" restriction might not be part of the original assignment.

Comment: The question says `jg` **or** `jle`. I [did it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8517852/968261) with only `jle`.

Comment: Also, `and eax, 0xFFFFFFFC`+`jle`+`jg` does not take care of the `eax=4` case. The condition in the question is `>`, not `>=`. And the signed/unsigned handing isn't quite right.

Comment: @Alex you are correct about =4, though strictly I would not accept your answer either - you don't jump to `do` while this is the requirement